# python lxml: find elements that do not have an ancestor of a specific type

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I need to find all elements which do not have a specific other element as any of their ancestors

Example:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <c name="Joe">
            <x>1</x>
        </c>
    </b>
    <d>2</d>
    <c name="Jane">3</c>
</a>
```

Assuming `a` is the root, I want to find all elements in `a` which do not have `b` as an ancestor. And with ancestor I mean the entire tree so in above example c-Joe and x should be excluded from result.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: How did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
//a//*[not(ancestor::b)]
```

to select all descendants of `a` that have no `b` ancestor or

```
//a//*[not(ancestor-or-self::b)]
```

to exclude all descendants + `b` node itself